# Is there a difference between the action android.settings.DATE_SETTINGS from a mobile device and a tablet?

Tags: android, mdm

The issue I'm experimenting is mainly with tablet devices. We are deploying an MDM launcher with Workspace One UEM for those tablets and, since it's a very restricted profile, our users can't manually change date and time because they don't have that option by default, you can only see it if you access the launcher as an administrator via password.

We of course don't want to force our users to access the admin mode since they can quit the launcher by doing that so we tried implementing the action android.settings.DATE_SETTINGS as a custom setting on the launcher menu.

This action works perfectly fine with every mobile device we enroll, the new option appears on the last row of options, however when it comes to tablets it doesn't appear anywhere and you can only access to the option with the admin mode...

Is there a difference between the action mobile devices have and the action tablet devices have for the action to open date and time screen? My next step was trying to extract the androidmanifest.xml from a tablet.